# ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder collect values incorrectly collects first iteration through conditional

Tags: arcgis-pro, modelbuilder

[image: Model in question]

Model iterates through TIFF files and clips it to area of interest. The conditional starts at the top with Calculate Value(2). It takes the [2:10] chars of the file name to assess if it's the months and variable I want to analyze (Multiple value string input). Although it registers false, the Collect Values (2) and Output Values(2) always has its first entry as whatever the first TIFF file is "loaded" in the model. Here I just wanted the last 3 entries that passed the conditional, not the first one.

[image: Model as a submodel with outputs displayed]

I don't mind a workaround that removes the first entry of the output values, I just don't know what tools to use for that. Collect values tool to me has been one weird black box I can't even assess in the Python export window. Everything else is working as expected.

Comment: What do you do with the Collects value output, not the Collects value (2). You do not expose it as a parameter, can it be deleted and then try running the model?

Comment: Sure. I tried it as you mentioned and also made it the only collects value in the model (and deleted/reintroduced). Unfortunately, it still catches one tiff outside of the conditional.

Comment: I revisited this problem, although I changed the conditional variables a bit, the collect values still displayed an incorrect tif at the top. But, this is only for the modelbuilder UI. When adding the collected values to a map, only the rasters that passed the conditional get displayed. This also extends to tools that utilize the model output. So it seems like a visual UI bug...

Comment: You should report that to ESRI.